# Добавить видео в sip звонок

Tags: asterisk, sip, rtsp

Доброго времени суток !

Имеется звуковой SIP звонок приходящий из облака на мой asterisk, есть отдельно RTSP поток

Так вот, можно как-то на уровне астериска подмешать видео к сип звонку (по аналогии микширования звука и видео в ffmpeg), чтоб к клиенту звонок прилетел уже с видео ?